# Count frequency of digits in string

Tags: c, string, loops, frequency, digits

I need to implement a function that can count the number of digits in a string. So for numbers but also for somehting like: aD23b. If I could make it work...it should look like: 
Input: 0912302 
Output: 
0: 2 
1: 1 
2: 2 
3: 1 
4: 0 
5: 0 
6: 0 
7: 0 
8: 0 
9: 1

At this point I can't code anything that works unfortunately...My basic idea is: Use a loop to check every character from Input, if it's a digit, store it in a second array (let's say frequency). The problems I have are that I need to somehow convert every character into a integer or somehow be able to count how 
often each digits appears... I was hoping this might work but it doesn't at all:

I forgot to mention I'm a beginner in programming so I would really appreciate if you could give me tips and explanations.

```
void calc_occurrences(int s[], int occurrences[])
{
int i = 0;
    int j;
    int count = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (isdigit(s[i])) {
            for (j = 0; occurrences[j] != '\0'; j++) {
                occurrences[j] = s[i];
            }
        }
        i++;
        for (j = i + 1; s[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (isdigit(s[i]) == isdigit(s[j])) {
                count++;
                occurrences[j] = 0;
            }
        }

        if(occurrences[i] != 0) {
            occurrences[i] = count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "At this point I can't code anything that works" Well, posted whatever you have... then we can help you fix it

Comment: If you want the most efficient solution, consider using a data structure called map, which essentially holds key-value pairs. Though it can be very inefficient, you might want to start by using arrays for mapping your occurrences.

Comment: @ionizer A map is not a standard type in C like in C++

Comment: I'm not saying about using a library or anything though, just the data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array to count the frequency of each relevant character.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count_freq(char* str, int freq[10])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i])  // Loop to end of string
    {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') // Check that the character is in range
        {
            ++freq[str[i]-'0'];  // notice the -'0' to get in range 0..9
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int freq[10] = {0};             // Array to count occurence
    char str[] = "0034364hh324h34"; // Input string

    count_freq(str, freq);          // Calculate frequency

    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)      // Print result
    {
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, freq[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0: 2
1: 0
2: 1
3: 4
4: 4
5: 0
6: 1
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
```

Comment: so while(str[i]) is the same as while(str[i] != '\0') ?? and another question what does ++freq[str[i]-'0']; do ? i get the part with str[i]-'0' that way you solve the problem of converting the char back to integer, but what does ++freq mean ?

Comment: @Saty yes `while(str[i])` is the same as `while(str[i] != '\0')`

Comment: @saty `++X` is the same as `X = X + 1;`

Comment: Marginal — it won't affect my up-vote or the OP's accept, so it's your call.

Comment: @4386427 ok so i'm still trying to understand how you store the numbers in freq[]...if i understood it correctly, freq[10] = {0} so every element is 0. If s[] is a digit at index i, then you add + 1 to the freq[] at the index s[i] - '0'. so if s[i] = '3' then you convert it to int so you have 3 and add +1 to freq[3] = 0 + 1 ?

Comment: @4386427 one last question, I was trying to write the code from scratch using your logic  and not actually looking at the solution...does it make a difference if I write ++freq[str[i]-'0']; or freq[str[i]-'0']++; ? in general ++i and i++ is still a bit confusing for me

Comment: @Saty In this case it makes no difference. But it does in other cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can have an integer array with size 10 with 0 stored in all indices. Then, when you spot a digit, you can increment the number in the respective index.

In example, when you see a "0", you can do arr[0]++;.

Also, you may check if a character is a digit with the isdigit() function.

Answer (score 0):

PS : I know, I'm answering an old post, but I was doing some challenges on HackerRank, and I managed to solve this nearly exact problem, in case it might help someone since I've used dynamic allocation on my code.

```
/* Problem: hackkerrank.com/challenges/frequency-of-digits-1/problem */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    *s;
    int   *arr;
    int    i;

    i = 0;
    s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", s);
    arr = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    while(i < 10)
    {
        *(arr + i) = 0;
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(s))
    {
        if (*(s + i) >= '0' && *(s + i) <= '9')
        {
            (*(arr + (*(s + i) - '0'))) += 1;

        }
        i++; 
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i)); // As HackerRank problem wanted the output format.
        // printf("%d: %d\n", i, *(arr + i));  As you wanted it
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); scanf("%s", s);`  leads to UB as memory allocation is too small.